Listing imported functions from a Windows PE file
I am trying to recover the imported functions from a PE file. The code looks for call instructions in the disassembled .text section and then checks the call destination address against the function addresses in the IAT. However, none of the call destination addresses match up with the function addresses in the IAT. What am I doing wrong?
import sys
import pefile
from capstone import *

def valid_pefile(file_path):
    """
     Validates the input file as a PE file.
     Args: the path to the PE file
     Returns: pe file or None if the file is not a PE file """
    try:
        pe = pefile.PE(file_path)
        return pe
    except pefile.PEFormatError as pe_err:
        print("[-] error while parsing file {}:\n\t{}".format(file_path,pe_err))
        return None

def get_imported_functions(pe,ins):
    """
    Extracts the imported functions from a PE file.
    Args: pe file and disassembled.
    Returns: A list of imported functions.
    """
    imported_calls = []
    for (address, size, mnemonic, op_str) in ins:
        if mnemonic == 'call' and op_str.startswith('0x'):
            # Get the virtual address of the call destination
            va = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase + int(op_str, 16)
            # debug: print("Call destination address: " + str(hex(va)))
            # Check if the destination address matches an IAT entry
            for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
                for imp in entry.imports:
                    # debug: print("IAT func address: " + str(hex(imp.address)))
                    if imp.address == va:
                        imported_calls.append({
                            'function_name': imp.name.decode(),
                            'call_address': hex(address),
                            'rva': hex(address - pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase)
                        })
                        break

    return imported_calls



def disassemble_code(code, offset=1000):
    """
    Disassembles x86-64 binary code section.
    Args: binary_data (bytes): The raw binary data to be disassembled.
    Returns: A list of disassembled instructions in tuple form.
    """
    try:
        # Initialize the Capstone disassembler
        md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)

        # Disassemble the binary data
        instructions = md.disasm_lite(code, offset)
        return instructions
    except CsError as e:
        print(f"Disassembly error: {e}")
        return None



def get_text_section(pe):
    """
    Extracts the .text section from a PE file and prints its starting point and size.
    Args: file_path (str): The path to the PE file.
    Returns: contents of the .text section.
    """
    if pe is not None:
        text_section = next((section for section in pe.sections if section.Name.decode().strip('\x00') == '.text'), None)
        if text_section:
            text_data = text_section.get_data()
            text_start = text_section.VirtualAddress
            text_size = text_section.Misc_VirtualSize
            # debugging
            # print(f"The .text section starts at virtual address 0x{text_start:08X} and has a size of {text_size} bytes.")
            return text_data, text_start
        else:
            return None
    else:
        print("Error while parsing PE file: {}".format(pe))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pe = valid_pefile(sys.argv[1])
    code, address = get_text_section(pe)
    ins = disassemble_code(code, address)
    calls = get_imported_functions(pe,ins)
    for call in calls:
        print(f"Function name: {call['function_name']}, Call address: {call['call_address']}, RVA: {call['rva']}")

The IAT addresses seem to be higher than the call function destination addresses, e.g., Call dest add: 0x140005de8, IAT func add: 0x140007300.
Edit:
I I have tried several (benign) executables. The Call det addresses seem to be always larger.
Example Output:
Call dest addresses     IAT func addresses
0x140005de8         0x140007300
0x140005de8         0x140007308
0x140005de8         0x140007310
0x140005de8         0x140007318
0x140005de8         0x140007320
0x140005d9c         0x140007328
0x140005de8         0x140007330
0x14000107c         0x140007338
0x140005de8         0x140007340
0x140005d9c         0x140007348
0x140005de8         0x140007350
0x14000107c         0x140007358
0x14000107c         0x140007360
0x140005d9c         0x140007368


So I managed to solve this myself. I reversed the binary in Ghidra and noticed that calls to the functions listed in the IAT were in relative addressing form, e.g., call qword ptr [rip + 0x6325]. So it was just a case of calculating the value for rip (current instruction address + length of the instruction) and then add it to the displacement. Can someone with enough rep points please mark this as closed?

calls will be empty because the imported functions aren't located in code. Instead, it's located in import table.
They are imported functions, not local functions.
About the question, to list the imported functions, you need to iterate through DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT and ImportDescData.imports, like this code:
for desc in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
    print(desc.dll.decode())
    for entry in x.imports:
        print(entry.name.decode(),entry.address)

        
KERNEL32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
USER32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
GDI32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
SHELL32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
ADVAPI32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
COMCTL32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
ole32.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600
VERSION.dll
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA 4223592
GetFileVersionInfoA 4223596
VerQueryValueA 4223600

